# PayPal Sandbox We're sorry, things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

```
 <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="pay" class="pay" id="pay" method="POST" onsubmit="return true">
                    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="MY EMAIL">
                    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
                    <input type="hidden" id="item_name" name="item_name" value="test">
                    <input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" value="00">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="SGD">
                    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">

                    <!-- Specify URLs -->
                    <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='<?=base_url('/order/cancel/')?>'>
                    <input type='hidden' id="return" name='return' value='<?=base_url('/order/success/')?>'>
                    <input type='hidden' id="notify_url" name='notify_url' value='<?=base_url('/order/ipn/')?>'>
```

This is my form. And i pass value in by AJAX

```
    {
        var quantity = $(this).val();
        var amount = $('#amount');
        var item_name = $('#item_name');
        var email = '<?=$this->session->userdata('email').'@insead.edu'?>';

        if(quantity == 'one') {
            amount.val('23.54');
            item_name.val(email+' & 1 Box');
            return true;
        }

        else if(quantity == 'two') {
            amount.val('34.24');
            item_name.val(email + ' & 2 Box');
        }
        else {
            amount.val('00');
            item_name.val(email);
            return true;
        }
```

It works like charm until today. I didn't modify anything. And I launch my localhost on LAMPP suddenly can't process with PayPal. I found that if the

```
<input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" value="00">
```

value is set to 1 or more will not work. if 00 will redirect me to paypal to enter the total amount. Just happened and I got no clue why. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the PayPal documentation?

Comment: It works now. The problem came from PayPal sandbox. Need some time until it get back stable.

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Two days until I can mark.

Comment: @aarontheam Can you tell what was the exact problem and how you correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now. The problem came from PayPal sandbox. Need some time until it get back stable.